# Retrieving xml attribute using Xquery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I am using the below query to select the values of XML from attributes ad elements of the XML file but I am not able to read the `seq, id, reported dated` attributes from XML page 
so any one please suggest How to get values of attributes using this Query.

```
select a_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'var char(50)') AS c_val,
c1_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'var char(50)') AS c_val 2,
ca_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'var char(50)') AS c_val3, 
d_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'var char(50)') ,
e_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') ,
f_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'var char(50)') 
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/Reports/x:InquiryResponse/x:ReportData/x:AccountDetails/x:Account') AS b(b_node) 
outer APPLY b.b_node.nodes('./x:primarykey') AS pK_InquiryResponse (a_node) 
outer APPLY b.b_node.nodes('./x:seq') AS CustomerCode (c1_node) 
outer APPLY b.b_node.nodes('./x:id') AS amount (ca_node)
outer APPLY b.b_node.nodes('./x:ReportedDate') AS CustRefField (d_node)
outer APPLY b.b_node.nodes('./x:AccountNumber') AS ReportOrderNO (e_node)
outer apply b.b_node.nodes('./x:CurrentBalance') as additional_id (f_node);
```

**Edit**: Xml Snippets Provided in Comments

```
<sch:Account seq="2" id="345778174" ReportedDate="2014-01-01">
    <sch:AccountNumber>TSTC1595</sch:AccountNumber>
    <sch:CurrentBalance>0</sch:CurrentBalance>
    <sch:Institution>Muthoot Fincorp Limited</sch:Institution>
    <sch:PastDueAmount>0</sch:PastDueAmount>
    <sch:DisbursedAmount>12000</sch:DisbursedAmount>
    <sch:LoanCategory>JOG Group</sch:LoanCategory>
</sch:Account>

<sch:Account seq="2" id="345778174" ReportedDate="2014-01-01">
    <sch:BranchIDMFI>THRISSUR ROAD</sch:BranchIDMFI>
    <sch:KendraIDMFI>COSTCO/RECENT-107</sch:KendraIDMFI>
</sch:Account>
```

Comment: SqlServer tag? Also, could you provide a snippet of Xml?

Answer (score 4):

**Parsing XQuery with an Xml Loose @Variable**

Assuming an Xml document similar to this (viz with all the attributes on one element):

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML = 
N'<Reports xmlns:x="http://foo">
    <x:InquiryResponse>
        <x:ReportData>
            <x:AccountDetails>
                <x:Account x:primarykey="pk" x:seq="sq" x:id="id"
                             x:ReportedDate="2014-01-01T00:00:00" />
            </x:AccountDetails>
        </x:ReportData>
    </x:InquiryResponse>
</Reports>';
```

You can scrape the attributes out as follows:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://foo' AS x)
select 
    Nodes.node.value('(@x:primarykey)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val,
    Nodes.node.value('(@x:seq)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val2,
    Nodes.node.value('(@x:id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val3, 
    Nodes.node.value('(@x:ReportedDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') as someDateTime
FROM 
   @xmlData.nodes('/Reports/x:InquiryResponse/x:ReportData/x:AccountDetails/x:Account') 
   AS Nodes(node);
```

- Attributes don't need `text()` as they are automatically strings
- It is fairly unusual to have attributes in a namespace - drop the xmlns alias prefix if they aren't.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33400)

**Edit - Parsing Xml Column**

- Namespace dropped from the attributes 
  -Assumed that you have the data in a table, not a variable, hence the `APPLY` requirement. Note that `OUTER APPLY` will return nulls, e.g. useful only if you have rows with
  empty Xml or missing Xml Elements. `CROSS APPLY` is the norm (viz
  applying the xpath to each row selected on the LHS table)
- Elements are accessed similar to attributes, just without `@`

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://foo' AS x)
select 
    Nodes.node.value('(@seq)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val2,
    Nodes.node.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val3, 
    Nodes.node.value('(@ReportedDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') as someDateTime,
    Nodes.node.value('(x:AccountNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as accountNumber
FROM 
    MyXmlData z
    CROSS APPLY
z.XmlColumn.nodes('/Reports/x:InquiryResponse/x:ReportData/x:AccountDetails/x:Account') 
      AS Nodes(node);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a04e/1)

**Edit Xml File off Disk**

Here's the same thing for an xml file read from disk. Note that once you have the data in an `XML` variable (`@MyXmlData`) that you don't need to `CROSS APPLY` to anything - just supply xpath to select the appropriate node, and then scrape out the elements and attributes.

```
DECLARE @MyXmlData XML;
SET @MyXmlData = 
( SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK N'c:\temp\file3098.xml', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS MyXmlData );
-- Assuming all on the one element, no need for all the applies
-- attributes don't have a text axis (they are automatically strings

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://foo' AS x)
select 
    Nodes.node.value('(@seq)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val2,
    Nodes.node.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS c_val3, 
    Nodes.node.value('(@ReportedDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') as someDateTime,
    Nodes.node.value('(x:AccountNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as accountNumber
FROM 
      @MyXmlData.nodes('/Reports/x:InquiryResponse/x:ReportData/x:AccountDetails/x:Account') 
      AS Nodes(node);
```

Comment: You need to provide a decent sample of the input Xml - we aren't psychic :). Cross Apply is generally only needed when working with xml columns in a table, and your post references `@xmlData` which I have taken to mean an `XML` variable.

Comment: - <sch:Account seq="2" id="345778174" ReportedDate="2014-01-01">
  <sch:AccountNumber>TSTC1595</sch:AccountNumber> 
  <sch:CurrentBalance>0</sch:CurrentBalance> 
  <sch:Institution>Muthoot Fincorp Limited</sch:Institution> 
  <sch:PastDueAmount>0</sch:PastDueAmount> 
  <sch:DisbursedAmount>12000</sch:DisbursedAmount> 
  <sch:LoanCategory>JOG Group</sch:LoanCategory> 
  </sch:Account>

Comment: - <sch:Account seq="2" id="345778174" ReportedDate="2014-01-01">
  <sch:BranchIDMFI>THRISSUR ROAD</sch:BranchIDMFI> 
  <sch:KendraIDMFI>COSTCO/RECENT-107</sch:KendraIDMFI> 
  </sch:Account>

Comment: here after selecting the values and inserting into  table called account and columns such as seq, id , accountnumber, institution, etc

Comment: I've updated. I'm not sure of the relevance of the second snippet - is this why you want outer apply, viz that some elements are missing nodes?

Comment: 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Read_Frm_XML1, Line 13
Invalid object name 'MyXmlData'. while executing query please explain why u declare 'myxmldata'

Comment: DECLARE MyXmlData XML
SET @MyXmlData = (
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK  'path of xml.3098', SINGLE_CLOB
  ) AS MyXmlData 
) like this??

Comment: Added from Xml file on disk. Please, next time provide all the information that is needed to solve the question in your post :)

Comment: @senthil xquery is tied to the XML Data type in SqlServer. You can either use this directly on Xml `@Variables`, or indirectly Xml Columns using CROSS APPLY. You've got examples of parsing xml via variables, tables and disk files from my answer. There really isn't anything I can add here - dive in and learn!