# Filtering XML with SQL

Tags: sql, xml, filter, business-process-management

I am working on BPM and have extracted a large xml file which I now would like to filter using SQL. I would like to filter it so that I only extract the contractrole child objects with the "Role Type" of 101. My xml is something of the form:

```
<contract>
  <ContractRole>
    <ContractId>xxxgg</ContractId>
    <RoleType>104</RoleType>
    <LastUpdateDate>2014-04-01 12:34:12.84</LastUpdateDate>
  </ContractRole>
  <ContractRole>
    <ContractId>xxxaa</ContractId>
    <RoleType>100</RoleType>
    <LastUpdateDate>2014-04-01 12:34:12.84</LastUpdateDate>
  </ContractRole>
  <ContractRole>
    <ContractId>xxxdd</ContractId>
    <RoleType>101</RoleType>
    <LastUpdateDate>2014-04-01 12:34:12.84</LastUpdateDate> 
  </ContractRole>
<contract>
```

How could I filter away the entries with other role types than 101? I have little to no experience with SQL but I was hoping to use a SELECT statement WHERE roletype is 101. I can easily do this when calling the database directly, but here I need to extract the same information from the XML.

A random example online suggested something of the sort:

```
SELECT child.value('(LastUpdate/text())[1]', 'TIMESTAMP') AS [LastUpdateDate]
       , child.value('(ContractId/text())[1]', 'BIGINT') AS [Id]
   FROM [Contract] AS T
CROSS APPLY [ImportData].nodes('/Contract/ContractRole[RoleType/text() == "101"]') AS ImportData(child)
```

Can someone please clarify how I could conduct this filter. Do I need to declaire my xml a name before I select anything or how does it work?

Comment: Assuming this is Ms Sql Server? Is the Xml in a table as a column, or is it loose, e.g. a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is `SqlServer`, and that you have the `Xml` in a loose variable (otherwise you will need to CROSS APPLY to the table, but the form is the same (have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307537/314291) for working with Xml columns or Xml files direct from disk). Some notes:

- Note that xml is case sensitive, viz `contract` and `Contract` are not the same
- Xpath and xsl use a single `=` for equality
- `BIGINT` and one of the date types like `DATETIME` appear better fits for type mappings to the xml.
- `contract` closing tag typo.

```
SELECT node.value('(LastUpdateDate/text())[1]', 'DATETIME') AS [LastUpdateDate]
       , node.value('(ContractId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Id]
   FROM @x.nodes('/contract/ContractRole[RoleType/text() = "101"]') AS nodes(node);
```

I've assumed the following:

```
DECLARE @x XML = 
'<contract>
  <ContractRole>
    <ContractId>xxxgg</ContractId>
    <RoleType>104</RoleType>
    <LastUpdateDate>2014-04-01 12:34:12.84</LastUpdateDate>
  </ContractRole>
  <ContractRole>
    <ContractId>xxxaa</ContractId>
    <RoleType>100</RoleType>
    <LastUpdateDate>2014-04-01 12:34:12.84</LastUpdateDate>
  </ContractRole>
  <ContractRole>
    <ContractId>xxxdd</ContractId>
    <RoleType>101</RoleType>
    <LastUpdateDate>2014-04-01 12:34:12.84</LastUpdateDate> 
  </ContractRole>
</contract>';
```

Returns

```
LastUpdateDate          Id
----------------------- --------------------
2014-04-01 12:34:12.840 xxxdd
```